# KIbana not getting connected to elastic search

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I have setup a cluster on aws using kops.

I have installed elasticsearch, kibana and fluentd in a namespace `logging`.

I also created an ingress routing for the same.

I can access the kibana dashboard, but when I try to create index; It asks for adding integration like below.

[image: kibana-dashboard]

How Can I connect it with elastic search and get all logs from fluetnd?

Update:

For installation of kibana I use below [helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/kibana),

```
helm install kibana elastic/kibana -n logging
```

For elasticsearch I use below [helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch),

```
helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -n logging
```

For installing fluentd I useda,

```
helm install fluentd bitnami/fluentd -n logging
```

Comment: Can you share the Kibana config file you used? And the service URL of Elasticsearch?

Comment: @KamolHasan I have update with details

Comment: @KamolHasan `elasticsearch-master` is the service name and the default url to kibana is `http://elasticsearch-master:9200`. They are in the same namespace `logging`, Is it fine?

Comment: Have you set `ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME` and `ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD` in `env` of Kinaba?

Comment: I didn't specify those, I just those charts in helm. I think it must be using default.